# how to gather all module's loggers under one parent?

Tags: python, logging

I understand and like the idea of hierarchical structure of loggers with canonical module name as the name of the logger. But I don't know how to tie everything up at the top level.
Supposing I have application using

**package1.subpackage1.module1** and

**package2.subpackage2.module2**.

And now I'd like to define one handler and one formatter for all. But I don't want to enumerate all module's loggers and setup them separately.
It seems that all module loggers should be automagically attached somewhere to "master" logger, where the only handler is defined. 
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer. The master parent for all loggers is root logger - no mater it's name doesn't appear in the canonical name.